# Then is not a function on axios async/await post request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, axios, ecmascript-2016

I am registering user via a `POST` request.

To do this, I am using axios with async/await! However, I am getting `register.then is not a function` error. Please help me out.

```
async sendUserData() {
  try {
    const register = await axios.post('/register', {
      email: this.register.email.trim(),
      password: this.register.password.trim(),
    });
    register.then(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `await` keywords awaits a promise (that means it internally handles the `then`) but it does not return a promise. Instead `await` returns the result of the promise.

Therefore, the correct way to do what you want is:

```
async sendUserData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/register', {
      email: this.register.email.trim(),
      password: this.register.password.trim(),
    });

    console.log(response);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

However, the `async` keyword returns a promise. So you should call your function like this:

```
sendUserData().then(console.log('done'));
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. But before I can mark this as the answer, will you please tell me if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaybanjade/dyrgxq8n/4/) is the correct approach?

Comment: @Sanjay No, if you are going to use `then()` you should remove both the keywords `await` and `async`

Comment: NOTE: In case of error --- e.response.data --- will have the actual error.